# Pulling data from a text file to generate a report

Tags: ms-access, vba

Have a program in MS-Access, using VBA. I need to come up with an If statement to pull data from a text file. The data is a list of procedures and prices. I have to pull the prices from the text file to show in a report how much each procedure costs.

```
ID     PID                    M1      M2     M3    Total      
1     11120390(procedure)    
2       180(price)           360     180     540     1080(total Price)
3                             2       1       3       6(Units sold)
4       
5       200(Price)           200     600     800     1600(total price)
6                             1       3       4       8(Units Sold)
7     11120390(procedure)
```

The table in the text file is setup like this and I need to Pull the procedure number and the price of each procedure from the text file.

Comment: sorry, my table looks nothing like it should

Comment: @Edmond, you can select text and format it as code when you edit the question.

Comment: what are the separators between data in you text file?

Comment: @Simon by separators you mean??

Comment: You are parsing a text file right?  Using your above table, what characters exist between id=1 and PID=11120390 in your text file?  It should be a TAB or a comma or spaces or some other delimiter/seperator.  Depending on how your text file is structured internally you will have different jobs/options for parsing it into the bits that you need.  As a general statement you don't "pull data from a text file" with "an if statement".  You have to parse the text file and for that you need to know how it is structured and that normally means knowing the delmiters between fields.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general answer to a vaguely-presented question.  You typically have to go through these steps:

1. Make a connection to the file
2. Open the file
3. Parse the file (as Simon was
   saying):  go through it as a series
   of strings, find an orientation
   point, get to the relevant parts
4. Import the relevant parts, perhaps
   in a holding table
5. Present the data in typical Access
   fashion (query, report)

And if the file isn't well structured or correctly generated, you'll need extra parsing code and perhaps error handling to deal with aberrations.